# How to select class elements within a relative parent inside draggable and droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM that looks something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="droppable"/>
    <div class="items-wrapper"/>

    <div class="droppable"/>
    <div class="items-wrapper">
        <div class="draggable">
        <div class="draggable">
    </div>
    <div class="droppable"/>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="droppable"/>
    <div class="items-wrapper"/>

    <div class="droppable"/>
    <div class="items-wrapper">
        <div class="draggable">
        <div class="draggable">
    </div>
    <div class="droppable"/>
</div>
```

In my javascript using JQuery, I want to set the "accept" selector of each droppable to get all the draggable items within the parent "wrapper" but it seems that inside the droppable options I lose access to $(this) making the following invalid.

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: "$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.file_item')",
});
```

I'm a bit of a novice so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not you store $(this) into a global variable like this - 
this1 = $(this) and after that you can use it by using that variable name in place of $(this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

droppable accept option can be a selector or function(). In your case use function.

```
 accept: function(ele) { 
    ele.closest('.wrapper').find('.file_item');
 }
```

link to [documentaion](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept)

Also the function must return true if the draggable should be accepted.

Comment: I missed that the accept function took the element itself in the function, I misread and thought it took the droppable. This works perfectly. Thanks.